# How to set variable in a Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, command-line

In my project I have a piece of code which executes a command:

```
Remove-Item -path \\D$\folder_name\* -recurse -force
```

Is there some way to save the path into a variable?

Something like:

```
Remove-Item -path ${path} -recurse -force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like this:

```
$Path = "\\$\folder_name\*"
```

And then pass it to the Remove-Item cmdlet:

```
Remove-Item -Path $Path -Recurse -Force
```